# How to run Openvpn Access Server and PPTPD (pptp server) at the same time?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, pptp

OpenVPN Access Server relies heavily on iptables rules. And adding PPTP network interfaces may interfere with AS operation.
I desperately need help getting two services to run properly on the same Ubuntu 10.04 x64 server.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to share the networks.
E.g.:
Your openvpn server does have the ip 10.0.0.1. The clients do have the ip range 10.0.0.20-40.
Then you can put following values to your /etc/pptpd.conf:
localip 10.0.0.110
remoteip 10.0.0.111-119

I am using this setup because I needed a pptpd instance for my ipad. I did not find a working solution for openvpn within iOS.